# QGIS: extract point features not in polygons

Tags: qgis, extract

I have a layer of approximately 2M point features from which I need to create a second layer, only including the points that are not within (or bordering on) a set of polygons that are saved in another layer.

Can QGIS handle this? Extract by location seems to only include options if you want to keep the points that are *within* other polygons.

I'm using QGIS 3.14

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is **Processing > Toolbox > Vector selection > Extract by Location**, using the *Disjoint* option:

[image]

The [Help page](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbylocation) describes the tool quite well.

Comment: This is new, or did I really forget about it?

Comment: I keep a copy of 2.18, and disjoint is also available there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `select by location` tool, select all points within the polygons and then reverse the selection. Though I don't know how the tool handles datasets this large.